# Setting up node debug running in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

So I have spent the last two days (and nights) fruitlessly trying to setup debugger in VS Code to debug my node app running in Docker. I have 3 days of experience with Docker at this point and before someone with really excellent reflexes marks it as duplicate, I have already read every blog post/answer from the first page of Google search result (it's true!) and I have no idea where else I can go. I am in tears. Please have a look and point out the stupid mistake I am probably making. Here are my relevant settings:

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node .",
"lint": "eslint **/*.js",
"dev": "nodemon --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 --watch src --exec node -r dotenv/config ."
},
```

(that `--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229` was added by me following advice from [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58716) issue report)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN apk --update add git ffmpeg imagemagick ghostscript poppler-utils libpng-dev

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN npm i

ENTRYPOINT node .
```

Here is the launch config

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
        "port": 9229,
        "address": "localhost",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "remoteRoot": "/app",
        "protocol": "inspector"
    },
```

And here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:

lil-upload:
environment: #redacted

image: 'pdffix'
ports:
- '8080:64544'
- '9229:9229'
restart: always
```

As I understand, I need to expose the port from docker that the debugger will attach on (9229 in this case) and when I launch the debugger, it will attach there. But every time I keep getting this error `Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: read ECONNRESET)`

And if change the config in my launch.json to `launch` instead of `attach` so that I can directly launch the app in debug mode, I get `Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229)` 
I have really no idea what else I need to do for this damn thing to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally. Being the idiot I am and not knowing the property of `ENTRYPOINT` in Dockerfile, I was making the script run the default script instead of running `dev` that I wanted. Just fixed the `ENTRYPOINT` and made it `npm run dev` and the whole world is sunshine and rainbows again. Thanks to everyone who didn't respond.